# MongoError: pool destroyed when called by lambda, but not by code from same server

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, lambda

Suddenly this morning our lambda based endpoint failed to connect to our ec2 based mongodb. It will just return the error `{ MongoError: pool destroyed`

But my nodejs code that's inside the same ec2 server with mongodb can access mongodb without any problem. Below is the mongodb connection code that we call from each of our lambda function.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let isConnected;
module.exports = connectToDatabase = () => {
 if (isConnected) {
   console.log('=> using existing database connection');
   return Promise.resolve();
 }
 console.log('=> using new database connection');
 return mongoose.connect('mongodb://123.456.789.123:27017/musleh-api')
   .then(db => {
     isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
   });
};
```

Code above is called by

```
const connectToDatabase = require("./../../db_mongo.js");
const handler = (req, res) => {

connectToDatabase().then(() => {
        console.log("67 dlm connectToDatabase")
        processSubmission(email,password).catch(function(err){
          console.log("69 err");
          console.log(err);
          res.status(400).send({ success:false, msg: err.toString() });
          return false;
        })
    });
}
```

After about half and hour, suddenly our lambda can access our ec2 mongodb again, without any problem. So we're really baffled on why does this happens. Any clue?